# Transfering Data from Laptop to Desktop

Tags: hard-drive, transfer

I recently built a PC because I got tired of working on my laptop. Both machines are Ubuntu. I'd now like to transfer the contents of my laptop hard drive to my desktop computer.

Is there a way to do this without transferring everything to an external device? Surely it could be done over a LAN or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `openssh-server` and `scp` or `sftp`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've used scp, but that seems to be for targeting one file at a time and transferring it. I'm talking about moving well over 1,000 photos for example.

Comment: `scp -rp`; `-r` is recursive `-p` is preserve permissions and modification times.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch what exactly does that do?

Comment: Copy an entire directory and its' contents, instead of one file. Which is what you want. Samba is another good option.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks Elliot. Don't mean to be dense, but could you provide an example command?

Comment: `scp -rp myDirectory/ 192.168.2.3:/home/efrisch/myDirectory` to copy from the current computer to one at `192.168.2.3`; **or** `scp -rp 192.168.2.2:/home/efrisch/myDirectory .` to copy from a computer at `192.168.2.2` to the local computer.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You should post this in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use ssh, it provides secure file transfers. First, install the server on one (or both) machines,

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Then, you can use the command line to copy files, if you use `-r` it will copy recursively (and `-p` preserves permissions).

```
scp -rp myDirectory/ 192.168.2.3:/home/efrisch/myDirectory
```

to copy from the current computer to one at 192.168.2.3; or

```
scp -rp 192.168.2.2:/home/efrisch/myDirectory .
```

to copy from a computer at 192.168.2.2 to the local computer. **Or**, once you have the server running, open the address with gnome like

```
sftp://192.168.2.2/
```

**And**, you can also use `ssh-keygen` to create a [public/private key-pair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) and if you add the public key to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the remote serve it will no longer require authentication. **Or**, use [`samba`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment as I lack the reps.

I suggest creating a [samba share](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html) on the laptop, which can then be accessed by the desktop.

Excerpts from the link:

---

## Installation

---

The first step is to install the samba package. From a terminal prompt enter:

```
sudo apt install samba
```

## Configuration

---

The main Samba configuration file is located in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.

The default configuration file has a significant number of comments in order to document various configuration directives.

> Not all the available options are included in the default
>   configuration file. See the smb.confman page or the Samba HOWTO
>   Collection for more details.

### Step 1:

Edit the following key/value pairs in the *[global]* section of `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

```
workgroup = EXAMPLE
.
.
.
security = user
```

The **security** parameter is farther down in the *[global]* section, and is commented by default. Also, change EXAMPLE to better match your environment.

### Step 2:

Create a new section at the bottom of the file, or uncomment one of the examples, for the directory to be shared:

```
[share]
    comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
    path = /srv/samba/share
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0755
```

1. *comment*: a short description of the share. Adjust to fit your needs.
2. *path*: the path to the directory to share.

> This example uses /srv/samba/sharename because, according to the File
>   system Hierarchy Standard (FHS), /srv is where site-specific data
>   should be served. Technically Samba shares can be placed anywhere on
>   the file system as long as the permissions are correct, but adhering
>   to standards is recommended.

3. *browsable*: enables Windows clients to browse the shared directory
   using Windows Explorer.
4. *guest ok*: allows clients to connect to the share without supplying a
   password.
5. *read only*: determines if the share is read only or if write
   privileges are granted. Write privileges are allowed only when the
   value is no, as is seen in this example. If the value is yes, then
   access to the share is read only.
6. *create mask*: determines the permissions new files  will have when created.

### Step 3:

Now that Samba is configured, the directory needs to be created and the permissions changed. From a terminal enter:

```
sudo mkdir -p /srv/samba/share
sudo chown nobody:nogroup /srv/samba/share/
```

> The `-p` switch tells mkdir to create the entire directory tree if it
>   does not exist.

### Step 4:

Restart the samba services to enable the new configuration:

```
sudo systemctl restart smbd.service nmbd.service
```